# Is it possible to change the UIColorPickerViewController bar buttons

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uicolorpickerviewcontroller

Using the system `UIColorPickerViewController` is nice, but it would be nicer to customise the buttons at the top, specifically the X button which means 'finish' but could be considered confusing (it confirms, it doesn't cancel).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you can do some hacks by add this as a child in a view controller
This will hide its close button and you can embed in a navigation controller before add as child and to show your own left bar button item here you can use that navigation bar button.